What movie was this, set in a private school?
Most of the action took place in the 1975-1976 school year, except for a "reprise" that took place twenty-five years later in  2001.
The movie was about a favorite teacher, who taught Roman history. There was a scene of the first day lesson. A day two later, a new student, whose name I remember as "Sedgewick Bell" crashed the term. His father was a millionaire with plenty of influence who had just moved or was transferred, and Bell enrolled a day or two after the beginning of the term.
Bell was a lazy, indifferent student who made mostly "C's and D's," but somehow had a passion for Roman history. He did well enough to rank fourth in the class, but the teacher fudged his rank by "jumping" it to second, so that he could participate in oral quiz challenge before the whole school. Bell was the runner up, losing to a champion.
Twenty-five years later, Bell, now a smooth and accomplished politician, and the champion agreed to a public re-match of the oral quiz. Bell managed to match the champion question for question until he tripped on a topic that had been introduced on the first day, in the opening scene, before he had been enrolled.
He conceded gracefully, but his secret was revealed. Both times, he had a Roman history expert tell him the answers by a secret signaling mechanism. And the teacher, middle aged in the earlier going, now an old man, regretted fudging the original standings to give Bell this visibility.
What movie was this?

Google says Emile Hirsch played Sedgewick Bell in The Emperor's Club opposite Kevin Kline (William Hundert) and Jesse Eisenberg (Louis Masoudi).
Plot summary from IMBD:-

William Hundert is a passionate and principled Classics professor who
  finds his tightly-controlled world shaken and inexorably altered when
  a new student, Sedgewick Bell, walks into his classroom. What begins
  as a fierce battle of wills gives way to a close student-teacher
  relationship, but results in a life lesson for Hundert that will still
  haunt him a quarter of a century later.


I was beginning to think Walt never sleeps :-)

He does, but in weird hours. :) This is a duplicate, though
